# Bean Validation on JBoss EAP 6.2 works from time to time

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, rest, jboss

I work with JBoss EAP 6.2 and have the specific problem. I have 2 modules - core and app; there are some RESTful-services in both of them. I work with Resteasy 2.3.7.Final,validation-api 1.0.0.GA and hibernate-validator 4.3.1.Final, which has provided scope. All REST-methods looks like:

```
@Path("/modify")
@ValidateRequest
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response send(@Valid E data) {
//some business logic
}
```

Rest-validation works fine; but bean validation behaves very strange. If class with annotation @NotNull and rest-method ara located in a single module - everything OK, but if they are in different modules - validation works from time to time. I have no idea and I need help :(